# Compare Data tables

Tags: c#, datatable

I need to compare the two data table,
[image]

In both datatable we have the **systemuserid** . In datatable1 we have two rows.The system user id will start with **c2dd... and 53cf...**

Now i need to compare the two tables whther all systemuserids are available in second Datatable.

In these table the c2dd... sustem user is not available in the datatable 2. so i need to add that c2dd.. row in datatable 2 with noofCall as 0

Comment: @ghost I need to compare those tables in C# not in sql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have two `datatable` available, then you can compare two table and get `table1 row systemuserid`  which are not available in `table2` in following way :

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> differenceRows = table1.AsEnumerable()
                                    .Where(x => table2.AsEnumerable()
                                    .All(y => y.Field<string>("systemuserid") != x.Field<string>("systemuserid")));
```

After getting `differenceRows`,  you can add new row in table2 iterating through `differenceRows`.